# Python 27 scpclient timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7, scp

So - I am trying to get a file from point A to point B. I use the following piece of code:

```
from scp import SCPClient
try:
    scp = SCPClient(ssh_conn.get_transport())
    scp.get(X, Y)
    scp.close()
```

Everything was working well until the file grew big enough to raise timeout. Now I can not copy the file to point B anymore because it just times out with the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scp.py", line 415, in _recv_file
raise SCPException('Error receiving, socket.timeout')
scp.SCPException: Error receiving, socket.timeout
```

How do I increase the time or get rid of the timeout?

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
scp = SCPClient(ssh_conn.get_transport(), socket_timeout=your_timeout)
```